# Custom post type and category permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, permalinks

I would like the URL structure of my site to be like this:

```
http://localhost/testwp/books/education/my-title-book
```

I am using the WP Types plugin and I have created a custom post type, `books`, and a category, `education`. I have created a post in `books` and I have assigned it to `education`.

When I type `http://localhost/testwp/books/`, the permalink works fine, but when I type `http://localhost/testwp/books/education`, I get the message:

> «Oops! That page can’t be found»

Am I going in the right direction, or do I have to use custom-taxonomies instead of categories?

I also have the Custom Post Type Permalinks plugin installed.

Answer (score -1):

The permalinks settings will be like this:

```
example.com/custompost
example.com/category
example.com/customtax
```

So you can do:

```
localhost/testwp/education
```

Comment: thank you for your post but i would really like to stay in the url logic described before.

example.com/custompost 
example.com/custompost/category example.com/custompost/category/my-post

or

example.com/custompost 
example.com/custompost/customtax example.com/custompost/customtax/my-post

thank you